# How to build ionic application for 64 bit?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, 64-bit, app-bundle

I am having an application build in ionic 3. As google is changing his Google Play store policy for apk upload. I am having following query regarding it:- 
1. How to built 64-bit apk for ionic and cordova application with crosswalk install into it.
2. do we need to two different apps with same or different android android-versionCode for release?
3. How to start two different application upload in Google Play store?

Comment: what do you mean by 64 app ?

Comment: this can help you : https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: @Sam Yes, I have already check this link but how to install all the libraries of 64 bit into ionic app. As for my other concern that use of crosswalk. if use the cordova command to build the ionic app given into below link. 
[https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview#160-march-11-2016]

Then there will be two apk to upload on Google Play Store. Bigger issue is to maintain two different android-Versioncode for the single application.

Comment: Just build an app 64 bit and its will be good.

Comment: Okay @Sam how did you installed libraries into ionic app?

Comment: Update Cordova to the last version , same for your plugin, and build it . It will be an 64 bit app. Check if your app is a 64 bit with android studio

Comment: Okay @Sam I will try it out and update you.